# Looping through each item from JSON to display plane information

Tags: javascript, json

## Question

How can i set up a working example of of these planes.

---

### Background

I have the first part working, so it seems that perhaps my loop is off? I can at least pull the number of planes. But having a problem displaying all the planes.

Here is my [Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/ygqogm)

I am looking at the documentation from https://developers.wargaming.net/reference/all/wowp/encyclopedia/planes/?application_id=demo&r_realm=eu

but they don't have a fully functioning example. I want to show the name of the plane, country, and show a large image. I can style it later but need a working example to help me understand and get started.

---

### Code

#### API

I am pulling data from https://api.worldofwarplanes.eu/wowp/encyclopedia/planes/?application_id=demo

#### JSON output

[image]

#### HTML

```
<p>There are a total of <span id="planeQuantity"></span> planes in the database.</p>
<ul id="planes"></ul>
```

#### jQuery from

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

#### Javascript

```
var queryURL = "https://api.worldofwarplanes.eu/wowp/encyclopedia/planes/?application_id=demo";

$.getJSON(queryURL, function (data) {

  var quantity = data.meta.count;

  $('#planeQuantity').append( quantity );

  var name = data.id.name_i8n;
  var nation = data.id.nation;
  var lrgImg = data.id.images.large;

  $(data).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).id);
    $('#planes').append('<li>' + name + 'is from ' + nation + '<img src="' + lrgImg + '">' + '</li>');
  });

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted your code a bit. Some comments:

1. your `data.data` is a Object. so, you can use `for (key in object)` for each key iteration (you can use jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) too, but this is a pure JS approach);
2. `name_i8n` is, actually, `name_i18n`;
3. put all your `var = name`, `var = nation` and `var = lrgImg` into inside the loop.

Final code:

```
var queryURL = "https://api.worldofwarplanes.eu/wowp/encyclopedia/planes/?application_id=demo";

$.getJSON(queryURL, function (data) {

  var quantity = data.meta.count;

  $('#planeQuantity').append( quantity );

  for (key in data.data) {

    var item = data.data[key];

    var name = item.name_i18n;
    var nation = item.nation;
    var lrgImg = item.images.large;    

    $('#planes').append('<li>' + name + 'is from ' + nation + '<img src="' + lrgImg + '">' + '</li>');

  }
})
```

#### Working pen: **http://codepen.io/mrlew/pen/vgaexb**

---

**Edited with some explanation**

You received a `data` Object that have a `data` key whose value is a huge Object with this structure (more or less):

```
{
    "7290": { /* ... */ },
    "7291": {
        "name_i18n": "North American FJ-1 Fury",
        "nation":"usa",
        "images":{
            "large":"http://worldofwarplanes....png",
            /* ... */
        },
        /* ... */
    },
    "7292": { /* ... */ }

}
```

So, to iterate over all keys of `data.data` keys we can use `for (key in data.data) { }`.

In each iteration, `key` variable will be assigned to a object `key`: `7290`, `7291`, `7292`. So, to access it's value, we use `data.data[key]` (will be `data.data["7291"]`, for instance), and assigned the variable `item` with the value.

Using brackets like this is one way in JavaScript to retrieve a value from an Object. Another way is to use *dot notation* (but you can't use dot notation with a key that's a number).

This is valid:

```
data["data"]["7291"]
```

This is invalid:

```
data.data.7291
```

Comment: @JGallardo I edited with more explanation! Hope it helps

Comment: This is extremely helpful example. thank you so much, i know understand these concepts better.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the values of `name`, `nation` and `lrgImg` inside `each`. So the elements you append won't all have the same thing. And you should loop through the `data` object that is inside your `data` object (`data.data`). Like this:

```
var queryURL = "https://api.worldofwarplanes.eu/wowp/encyclopedia/planes/?application_id=demo";

$.getJSON(queryURL, function (data) {

  var quantity = data.meta.count;

  $('#planeQuantity').append( quantity );

  $.each(data.data, function(key, value){
    var name = value.name_i18n; // get the name of this data entry
    var nation = value.nation; // get the nation of this data entry
    var lrgImg = value.images.large; // ...

    $('#planes').append('<li>' + name + 'is from ' + nation + '<img src="' + lrgImg + '">' + '</li>');
  });
});
```

Comment: This does not work, but maybe i did something wrong. here is the codepen where I tried

http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/rjrGWw

Comment: with errors though :/ "undefinedis" here is the updated codepen with your code. are you testing it? http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/apjLKK

Comment: @JGallardo `name_i8n` should be `namei18n`. Updated!

Comment: @JGallardo yeah, I know!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir didn't know we could use jQuery `.each` to iterate over a Object keys. Always learning +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryURL = "https://api.worldofwarplanes.eu/wowp/encyclopedia/planes/? application_id=demo";

$.getJSON(queryURL, function (data) {
    var quantity = data.meta.count;
    $('#planeQuantity').append( quantity );

   $.each(data.data, function(i, e) {
       var name = e.name_i18n;
       var nation = e.nation;
       var lrgImg = e.images.large;

       $('#planes').append('<li>' + name + 'is from ' + nation + '<img src="' + lrgImg + '">' + '</li>');
   });
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, do you have a demo? can you explain to me the `, function(i, e)` I ask because someone did it differently

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate through `data.data` object. Since you aren't working with dom nodes use `$.each()` instead of `$.fn.each()`

```
$.each(data.data, function(key, obj){

   console.log(key) // "4101"
   console.log(obj.name) // "type=91"
})
```

Comment: I'm confused how to add this. your answer does not show any of the HTML

Comment: am showing you how to get `name` ... not hard to go from there to your html which would be same approach inside this loop

Comment: I think jQuery automatically switch to `$.fn` if the passed parameter is an object.

Comment: @charlietfl i appreciate your input but commenting that "it is not hard" is not helping.

Comment: just add your html line inside loop ..and modify your variables inside it to things like `obj.name` or `obj.images.small`

Comment: @charlietfl I'm curious why `each` didn't work for both of us!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir will work using `$.each`. It can iterate arrays OR objects http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @charlietfl I know that. That's why I confused why it didn't work. We must have forgot something!

Comment: I have never used `$.fn.each` on an object